# How do I get the unit test test name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unittest

I have written some unit tests. The base test is reusable and I use a validation function to log out failures with the tests name.  The examples say call id() or _testMethodName (unittest.TestCase.id()) but neither work since I'm no longer in the unittest class (python 2.7). In python I don't know how to dynamically get the active unittest runner.

If you run the example below you will see that it sometimes prints the reusable test name as the stack depth changes.  Work arounds are hackish.

This is just debugging code and the information is important since the log I have created needs to know the test name so additional information prints next to the test name.  I don't want the test writer to write additional code in his or her test.

```
import unittest
import inspect

currentFuncName = lambda n=0: sys._getframe(n + 3).f_code.co_name

def verify( expected, actual ):
    # 'id(): ' + str(unittest.TestCase.id())   # Something like this
    # print 'id: ' + str(id()).split()[4]      # a hack
    # 'curFrame(): ' + str(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name) # hack
    # 'stack: ' + str(inspect.stack()[2][3])   # a hack
    print 'curFuncName: ' + currentFuncName()  # a hack

# Reusable Test
def theTest( exp ):
    actual  = 'keith2'
    verify( exp, actual )

def otherTest( exp ):
    theTest( exp )

class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('mName: %s' % (self._testMethodName))
        # print('Short: %s' % (self.shortDescription()))    // Returns none

    def test_one(self):
        # print 'name: ' + str(self.TestCase.id())
        theTest( 'keith' )

    def test_two(self):
        otherTest( 'keith')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main( argv=sys.argv, testRunner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2))
```

Answer (score 2):

The asker's peculiar test setup is rather confusing and is more of an organizational issue. Just answering the question in the title, here's a minimal example which makes printing test names dead simple.

```
# tests/base_case.py
import unittest

class BaseCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # this gets run at the beginning of each test
        print('\n', unittest.TestCase.id(self))

# tests/test_something.py
from .base_case import BaseCase

class SomethingTestCase(BaseCase):
    def test_that_one_thing(self):
        # ...
    def test_that_other_thing(self):
        # ...
```

When the above tests are run, something like this gets printed:

```
tests.test_something.SomethingTestCase.test_that_one_thing
.
tests.test_something.SomethingTestCase.test_that_other_thing
.
```

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.shortDescription

> Returns a description of the test, or None if no description has been provided. The default implementation of this method returns the first line of the test method’s docstring, if available, or None.
>   Changed in version 3.1: In 3.1 this was changed to add the test name to the short description even in the presence of a docstring. This caused compatibility issues with unittest extensions and adding the test name was moved to the TextTestResult in Python 3.2.